# Why do heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors in logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

I am following a course on R. At the moment, we are working with logistic regression. The basic form we are taught is this one:

```
model <- glm(
  formula = y ~ x1 + x2,
  data = df,
  family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"),
  weights = weight
)
```

This makes perfectly sense to me. However, then we are being recommended to use the following to get coefficients and heteroscedasticity-robust inference:

```
model_rob <- lmtest::coeftest(model, sandwich::vcovHC(model))
```

This confuses me bit. Reading about `vcovHC` is states that it creates a "heteroskedasticity-consistent estimation". Why would you do this when doing logistic regression? I taught it did not assume homoscedasticity? Also, I am not sure what the `coeftest` does?

Comment: See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503092/heteroskedasticity-and-logistic-regression