# How to check heteroskedasticity in ordered logistic regressionmodels?

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, ordered-logit

When estimating an ordered logistic regression in R using `library(MASS)::polr` how can I check for heteroskedasticity and fit it if it's exist?
I'm self-studying the ordered logistic regression model, so I didn't covered in any classes. only for linear regressionmodels, such as BP test, chow test. As far I can find these methods are not used for ordered logistic regression.

Comment: by chance have you solved the problem and do you have the answer? it will be very usefull for me :)

Comment: There is no assumption of homoskedasticity for logistic regression! See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503092/heteroskedasticity-and-logistic-regression